# Python using mysql.connector.connect yields an Interface Error

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-code, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

When I execute the code

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="user",
  passwd="password"
)
```

I get:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

I've tried using an example with "pymysql' and the error stays.

I looked around the internet and a lot of people say it could be a firewall inbound problem. Yet there is no fire wall stopping 3306. The security group on Amazon RDS allows all connections. I connected the RDS instance to my local mySql Workbench (so I can make tables and stuff from there). Interestingly enough when I run the code and the error persists there is additional client connections that pop up. Anyone else deal with this? Thank you very much I'm trying to learn this part of AWS well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My host name should NOT be "localhost" it should be my endpoint on Amazon RDS. It seems clear now considering when I connected my RDS database to mySql workbench I put in "databasename.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" for my host name. Now I can connect and read/write to the database.